# Qt Style Sheet - Different styles for same type widgets

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I need to assign different styles for the same typed widget instances. Specially for QActions. Following style sheet sets QActions' background images, actualy tool buttons'.

```
QToolButton
{
    background-image: url(bg.png);
}
```

But I need to assign different backgrounds for tool buttons like this.

```
QToolButton::actClose
{
    background-image: url(close.png);
}
QToolButton::actOpen
{
    background-image: url(open.png);
}
```

Is there any easy way like this or is it not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can set object name for instances of QToolButton

```
QToolButton *button = new QToolButton;
button->setObjectName("firstButton");

button = new QToolButton;
button->setObjectName("secondButton");
```

and next use them in Style Sheet

```
QToolButton#firstButton 
{ 
   background-color: gray 
}

QToolButton#secondButton 
{ 
   background-color: red 
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work because it is not a tool button it is a QAction

Comment: `QAction` isn't a kind of `QWidget` so you can't set a background or image for it (inherent directly from `QObject`). `QToolButton` is a kind of `QWidget` associated with some action to it so could have a background, icon, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It helps if you can post c++ code that creates the QToolButton and associates with QActions.

Cite from QToolBar's reference "Toolbar buttons are added by adding actions, using addAction() or insertAction(). " and "QWidget  * QToolBar    widgetForAction (QAction  *action )const
Returns the widget associated with the specified action."

So if you are creating QToolBar and call QToolBar::addAction(QAction*) to fill it, it is possible to get pointer to the tool buttons. Try QToolBar::widgetForAction(), and call setObjectName("") and Blueman's method can be applied.

while applying Style Sheet to widgets, "#" is used after class name to specify object name, ":" is used after className of objectName indicating the object's status such like "enabled", "::" is used to specify the subcontrols such as "ListView::Item", unfortunately QAction is neither of QToolBar.