# checkbox stylesheet for different checked images in QT/PyQT, How?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtstylesheets

I have 2 checkboxes. One is for pass and the other for fail. I want a checkmark in the pass checkbox and an X in the fail checkbox. I have images for both checkmark and fail. If I put this style in the parent container, I get a checkmark in both.

> QCheckBox::indicator:checked {   image: url("./checkmark-on.png"); }

Obviously that doesn't work for the fail. I tried putting a similar style in the fail checkbox, but it doesn't seem to override the parent.

How do I override the parent?

Comment: Use [selector types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types), either by setting a proper [`objectName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop), a custom property or a specific class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qt Style Sheet - Different styles for same type widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967998/qt-style-sheet-different-styles-for-same-type-widgets)

Comment: I failed to state I am  trying to do this in QtDesigner, not in the code (hopefully). Also, there will be about 10 or more pairs of checkboxes like this. No, the referenced solution doesn't seem to apply from what I can tell.

Comment: Yes, it does. The point is to use a selector, that question uses object names, but even properties can be used. If you have more widgets that should follow the same rule, you can set a dynamic property for them (just select all related checkboxes and click the green "+" button in the property box of Designer to add a custom property - I'd suggest you to use a bool), then use the property selector: `QCheckBox[myProperty="true"]::indicator:checked { ... }`.

Comment: Just to be clear, I would put this in the parent?

Comment: Yes. Remember that the *cascading* concept of CSS is kept in QSS, so if you want to apply the same specific rule for a group of objects, you should put that rule at least to the closest common parent. But, in reality, the general suggestion is to avoid spreading CSS rules here and there (unless they are *specific* to a single widget), as it's common to forget rules written at previous stages of development, so you often end up in banging your head on the wall for hours because something doesn't work as expected, and then you realize you forgot a simple (and unrelated) rule somewhere else.

Comment: So, it's common practice to set a main stylesheet for the top level window, or, eventually, for very complex situations, just in the main parents/containers for which those rules would apply (in order to avoid writing long and complex selector rules). In fact, I normally avoid stylesheets in Designer at all, and I prefer setting a single *main* QSS on the QApplication instead.